# How to loop from 'a' to 'z' in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

is there a way to loop from 'a' to 'z' using th:each block of thymeleaf in a similar way we do using #numbers.sequence?

For the moment I am using a static array of chars in the back-and and passing this to the front-end.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```html
<div th:with="letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"
     th:each="num : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 25)}">
    <div th:text="${#strings.substring(letters, num, num+1)}"></div>
</div>
```

This still requires a hard-coded string (as you can see), which you could just as easily pass to Thymeleaf as a Java String (not as an array of chars). But maybe it's more acceptable than what you are currently doing.

I don't know of any way in which Thymeleaf can directly use Java's `(char)('A' + num)` technique - otherwise that would probably be what you are looking for. I think that is not possible. Unless/until someone proves it is possible.

---

**Update**

To prove myself somewhat wrong, I used the following approach:

```html
<div th:each="num : ${#numbers.sequence(97, 122)}">
    <div th:text="${#conversions.convert(num, 'java.lang.Character')}"></div>
</div>
```

This prints `a` through `z` by converting the decimal [ASCII values](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) to Java chars.

**However** this is only valid if you are using the Spring dialect of Thymeleaf - which is not mentioned in your question - so may be of no help to you.

---

A solution using the Thymeleaf standard dialect (no Spring) is to define a custom [conversion service](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conversion-services).

That requires more coding than your current approach - so again, is probably not what you want. But I mention it just in case. How you implement this depends more specifically on how you have integrated Thymeleaf into your program.

Comment: prefer to use 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.toCharArray() if I want to use such a solution...

Comment: Understood. I added another approach.

Comment: I like your second solution about converting ASCII values